# Disconnected NIC on customized & deployed Ubuntu 18.04 templates

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-vsphere, ubuntu-18.04, terraform, packer

Within my vSphere 6.7 U3 environment, I have an Ubuntu 18.04 template generated by packer which I am then using Terraform to deploy two copies of. I am running into an issue where the deployed VMs come up with their NIC's disconnected, preventing Terraform from completing the deployment.

I have followed the following KB from vmware: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/56409 though it is mentioned that this issue is supposed to be fixed in the release of vSphere and open-vm-tools that I am running. I have the fix outlined in the KB present in the template generated by packer.

```
To resolve this issue, follow below provided steps and do not skip the steps.

    Open the tmp.conf under /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf file.

Go to the line 11 and add the prefix # .

For example
#D /tmp 1777 root root -

    If you have open-vm-tools installed, open the /lib/systemd/system/open-vm-tools.service file.

         In certain version path may be different the use find command locate the file 
               #find  /  -iname  open-vm-tools.service
 
Add this line “After=dbus.service” under [Unit]
```

Has anyone else run into this? I am not using the cloud-init customization method. This is the only error I am seeing in the /var/log/vmware-imc/toolsDeployPkg.log file:

```
[2020-07-17T18:17:57.140Z] [   error] Customization command failed with exitcode: 2, stderr: 'Can't locate File/stat.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::stat module) (@INC contains: /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts/Utils.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts/Utils.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts/Customize.pl line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts/Customize.pl line 24.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[2020-07-17T18:17:57.140Z] [   error] Customization command failed with exitcode: 2, stderr: 'Can't locate File/stat.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::stat module) (@INC contains: /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /var/run/.vmware-imgcust-dk2xFAt/scripts/Utils.pm line 26.
```

`open-vm-tools` needs the package that contains `File/stat.pm`, which on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is `perl-modules-5.26`. Ensure that this package is installed.